# Leaps and Bounds

Tags: mathematics, animals

Cunning Coyote is in a race with Joe Jackrabbit. They both take the same size steps, but the coyote takes 14 steps in the time it takes the rabbit to take 9 steps. Cunning Coyote decided to let Joe get 60 steps ahead before he started to run.

How many steps will each runner take, **from the time the coyote started running** before the coyote catches up to the rabbit?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem can be put into an equation:

> $60 = (14-9)*c$, where x is the number of "time cycles" (of fourteen coyote steps and nine rabbit steps) that need to occur before the rabbit will be caught.

After

> $60/(14-9) = 12$ cycles, the rabbit will be caught. That's **168 steps for the coyote and 108 steps for the rabbit**. Note that the rabbit already took 60 steps, but the asker asked about the steps after the coyote started running.

Comment: rot13(Lbhe zngu vf vapbeerpg; sbhegrra zvahf avar vf svir, naq fvkgl qvivqrq ol svir vf gjryir, abg gra. Guvf jbhyq erfhyg va bar uhaqerq fvkgl-rvtug fgrcf sbe gur pblbgr (sbhegrra gvzrf gjryir) naq bar uhaqerq fvkgl-rvtug (avar gvzrf gjryir rdhnyf fvkgl, cyhf bar uhaqerq rvtug) sbe gur enoovg.)

Comment: haha wow I'm more tired than I thought. Thanks! @Meerkat